# why does the value of shared memory not change?

Tags: memory, multiprocessing, counter, shared

I have a multiprocessing program with  a shared variable "counter" . both parent and child change the value of counter ,so the final value of counter must be 20 but it types always zero with out any change .I have tried to define "counter" in many ways :as a global variable without shared memory and I got  result from 1 to 10 from parent and child ,as a shared memory and I defined it in many places and always get 0.
Can any one tell me why this happens ? why the value of counter is not from 1 to 20 ?? Is there any error in my code? and how can I change the DATASIZE to 1MB or 2 MB??

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#define SIZE1 sizeof(int)
#define DATASIZE (10<<20)
int *counter;
int main()
 {
double A[200][200];
double B[200][200];
double C[200][200];
int i, j, k, m; 
int outfile, result, count; 
unsigned seed;

struct timeval before, after;

char *buff;
pid_t child_pid ,wpid;
int child_status,shmid1;
key_t key1=2222;

buff = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(1<<20));

srandom(seed);

for (i=0; i<200; i++)
for (j=0; j<200; j++)
    {
    A[i][j] = random()/100.0;
    B[i][j] = random()/100.0;
}

 gettimeofday(&before, NULL);
 /*  counter = mmap(NULL, sizeof *counter, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,  MAP_SHARED       | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
   *counter=1;*/
 child_pid=fork();
 shmid1 = shmget(key1, SIZE1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
 counter = shmat(shmid1, NULL, 0);
 *counter=1;
 switch (child_pid)
     {
        case -1:
        {
               perror("\nfork failed\n");
               exit(1);
        }
        case 0:
            {
             /* shmid1 = shmget(key1, SIZE1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
               counter = shmat(shmid1, NULL, 0);*/

           printf("\nIam the child ,\n");

               for (m=0 ; m < 10; m++) 
                  {

                  outfile = open("testfile", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0777);
                  if (outfile <= 0)
                  perror("\nError opening file\n");
                  else 
                         {
                       result = write(outfile, buff, DATASIZE);
                       if (result <= 0)
                       perror("\nError writing file\n");
                     }
                 close(outfile);
                     *counter++;
                     printf("\ncounter from child %d",*counter);

               }              // end of for
             printf("\nI'm the Son, and exiting with status %d \n",child_status ); 
             exit(0);
          }                   // end of case 0
       default:                 // parent process - returns child ID
           {
                 /*shmid1 = shmget(key1, SIZE1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
                 counter = shmat(shmid1, NULL, 0);*/
          printf("\nIam the parent, my child process %d is \n",child_pid);

          for (m=0 ; m < 10; m++) 
              {

                     for (i=0; i<200; i++)
                       for (j=0; j<200; j++) 
                     {
                       C[i][j] = 0;
                       for (k=0; k<200; k++)
                           C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
                         }
                         *counter++;
                         printf("\ncounter from parent  %d",*counter);
             }// end of for

                  printf("\nIam the parent,  My child process  ID = %d \n",child_pid);

              }//end of default                     
                  waitpid(child_pid,&child_status,0);
    }//end of switch 
  //shmdt(counter);
  free(buff);
  gettimeofday(&after, NULL);
  count = (after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec) * 1e6;
  count += (after.tv_usec - before.tv_usec);

  printf("Total time in usec: %d\n", count);
  printf("\n multiprocessing end successfully ... \n");
  return 0;
   };
```